# The problem with users who forget to pick a best answer - and a possible solution

Tags: feature-request

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Force Accepted Answers on Questions by Inactive Users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8692/force-accepted-answers-on-questions-by-inactive-users)
>   [Encourage users to select ‘Accepted Answer’ for old Questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10672/encourage-users-to-select-accepted-answer-for-old-questions)

Many users ask questions, and community members, out of the goodness of their heart (and a desire to help others) answer them.

Here is the problem: many users forget to select a best answer to their question, thereby depriving the answerers of well-deserved rep.

I'm the type of person that likes to present a solution when I mention a problem. So here goes:

**Increase the rep for selecting a best answer to 3 or 4**
This is a no-brainer. The more you get for doing something, the more likely you are to do it.

**Automatically select a best answer when the following criterion are met:**

- The question is older than 7 days
- There are 2 or more answers to the question

The answer with the most upvotes is then selected.

Any thoughts or suggestions on this?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8692/force-accepted-answers-on-questions-by-inactive-users http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40087/encouraging-a-new-member-to-upvote-and-or-accept-an-answer-closed http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14994/do-you-feel-dirty-if-you-nudge-new-users-to-accept-your-answer-when-they-indicate http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12583/do-i-always-have-to-accept-an-answer http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10672/encourage-users-to-select-accepted-answer-for-old-questions

Comment: There seems to be no resolution to these...

Comment: There rarely is a resolution before a feature-request is suddenly implemented.

Comment: For example....

Comment: Acceptance is *completely* plenary, *not* mandatory, and *only* means that the OP used that answer in their solution. Nor is any answer, no matter how good, *entitled* to be accepted.

Comment: @dmckee - I'd like to see a penalty of -1 put on users who goad others on to pick a best answer. It happened to me a few times. it's patronizng , annoying, and ridiculous. Point-farming is annoying

Answer (score 3):

Disagree for automatic selection of answer

There is [Don't forget to accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14594/can-we-have-an-option-to-disable-the-dont-forget-to-accept-reminder) reminder already, it should be fine.

Comment: Why do you disagree? Some people don't even visit the site on a regular basis.

Comment: True, but for some questions there is more than one best answer, some most voted answer not always the best for OP, and forcing to accept by **bot** is not good idea. So, let's OP choose their choice.

Comment: Okay. Now we're getting somewhere. How can we encourage OPs to choose the best answer? Do they need an incentive?

Comment: @George, Yeah, we could encourage them by explaining in comments and also they would see that "don't forget to accept" reminder.

Comment: No, I have the solution now! Let's get moderators to pick the best answer.

Comment: @George - see above comment.  The highest voted answer is not always the one that works best for the OP; in fact, sometimes there may not even be an answer that works for the OP

Comment: @George - If I am not wrong, moderators couldn't mark as the answer for OP, may be its by-design. marking by unrelated persons could be biased and argumentative among other members too, so marking by moderators is not so good idea too.

Comment: Then is this the unsolvable problem?

Comment: Scratch that. I still think we could increase the rep earned for picking a best answer.

Comment: @George, you know, if you unmark the answer and select to another after period of time, you could get another rep, if 3 or 4 points, some people could try to game the system to get reps, thats not a good thing. Well, In My Honest Opinion, its not a problem, but its just a personal matter, cheers.

Answer (score 3):

While I agree that the more accepted answers the better, I do not agree with your proposed solution.

I would not be happy for the system to pick the best answer based on votes as this is not a good indicator of if that answer solved/answered the question.

I have asked questions and intentionally not marked any as answered because none solved my problem.

I don't have a better solution to offer, but this is not the right one IMHO.