# Some kind of respite for users who answers an unanswered questions and did not get any response

Tags: discussion, feature-request, reputation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The problem with users who forget to pick a best answer - and a possible solution](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42751/the-problem-with-users-who-forget-to-pick-a-best-answer-and-a-possible-solutio)

Many times the OP asks questions, and completely ignores the answers. For new questions it is still OK, as there is a fair chance of voting by other users.

When answering old questions, this is a real issue. I understand there a some badges to promote this, but if you see the **view count in some of the tags is really less**.

What I noticed with many people asking questions, and not minding the answer is that adding a comment to the question, such as "Did it help?" trigger some response.

What I am suggesting is that there should be some kind of respite for users who answer unanswered questions, and did not get any response.

When there is a **answer as unanswered questions** and  **in 2 days if there were** votes, no-comments (indicating the problems in the answer), and no other accepted answer, the user should get:

- some kind of message or indication that they have not-responded to an answer
- may be an e-mail
- the reputation increased of 1 or 2

If there is any kind of activity in the answer, it means that the answer has been at least been considered. If someone spend time in helping you, they at-least deserve a comment!

Comment: So if you don't tend to your older questions, you get poked. I like this idea.

Comment: **email** is a last option, if you get an answer, How long will it take you to comment on it? The no of view depends highly on the **tags**. I don't want to bother any one, but there some respite for the answers right?

Comment: The system already nudges users in their profiles about questions where they've not accepted an answer.

Comment: Plus we have no shortage of users to point out low acceptance rates...

Comment: Why is this closed as a dupe of a dupe?

Answer (score 10):

I very seldom comment on answers and we certainly don't need a bunch of "thank you" in comments. I'm thankful when I receive an answer, but the only "acknowledgement" the answerer should expect are the points they get for a good answer.

Answer (score 2):

Answering an old question bumps it to the front of the active queue.

That means that if you browse on https://stackoverflow.com/ instead of (say) https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=newest you'll see these again (at least for a short time). You'll have to ask the team what fraction of views come on the main page.

The thing is that questions that didn't get much attention the first time around are unlikely to get a lot on the second go either, unless someone have improved the question in some way.
You might consider editing the title of the post if it is obviously deficient.