# After what time should I accept an answer?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How long should I wait before accepting an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28550/how-long-should-i-wait-before-accepting-an-answer)

I got the needed answer, but the question seems popular and people continue to vote, comment and answer. If I will accept the favored answer, community will probably leave the question, as they won't have any motivation to answer or even view it.

How long is it ok to leave the question open on stackoverflow or programmers to allow everyone take part ? - Couple of days ? A week ?

Comment: See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28550/how-long-should-i-wait-before-accepting-an-answer

Comment: Consider http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/12583/139095 as well, specifically the point that you don't *have* to accept *any* answer unless or until you want to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's entirely up to you, although the SE software imposes a short delay before you can accept an answer.

After a few days, the system will remind you that an answer is not accepted.

Answer (score 5):

As long as it takes for you to get an answer that solves your problem.

If you're not happy with any of the answers you received, there's no need to accept any of them. Similarly, once you get the answer that you think fully answers your questions or solves your problem, accept it!

It's not uncommon for questions to receive late (and potentially better) answers after an answer was accepted, so I wouldn't worry too much about it *so long as the answer you accepted works for you*.